# How to call module export function from another file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, module-export

i am new in javascript/node js. So a little thing about function in js makes me confused. Here i have problem.

I have a function in a file (appModel.js) called `getUserById` to return a row from database by `id` as a parameter.

```
User.getUserById = function getUserById(id,result){
    var koneksi = new newDb();

    koneksi.query('Select ID, email, name, status, telp_no, company_id, created_at, updated_at from user where ID = ?',id)
        .then(rows=>{
            console.log("user: ",rows);
            result(null,rows);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log('error: ',err);
            koneksi.close().then(()=>result(err,null));
        });
};

module.exports = User;
```

and i access appModel file through different file from (appRoute.js) using

```
var User = require('../models/appModel');
```

I've tried to access getUserById function in appRoute.js by

```
var _a;
var _check = User.getUserById(req.params.id, function(err,user){
    if(err){
        _a = err;
    }else{
        _a = user;
    }
    return _a;
});
console.log('res', _check);
```

when i print `_check` itself the result is `res undefined`

so, i expect the output from this function is an `error` or `user` itself.
How can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't actually modules related.

Its actually a lack of understanding of asynchronous processes and closures in general.

If you add a console.log in there as follows, you'll find that your 'res' runs before 'done'.

```
var _a;
var _check = User.getUserById(req.params.id, function(err,user){
    console.log('done', err, user); // <-- Add this in here.
    if(err){
        _a = err;
    }else{
        _a = user;
    }
    return _a;
});
console.log('res', _check);
```

The second part about closures, the return value in here is ignored:

```
_check = User.getUserById(req.params.id, function(err,user){
   ... 
   return _a; // This is ignored. It will never be assigned to _check.
}
```

The return value actually comes from:

```
function getUserById(id,result){
    var koneksi = new newDb();

    ...

    return "test"; // Here. Add this last line and try again.
};
```

Comment: You're right about the lack of understanding of asynchronous processes but, according to how is User.getUserById defined, where result is a callback function, the code should be more like this: var _check; User.getUserById(req.params.id, function(err,user){ if (!err) _check = user; console.log('res', _check)});

Comment: @ VirgilioGM I'm just teaching the OP how to understand what's going on with his code.
One should avoid using globals, mixing synchronous and asynchronous processes, callbacks and promises.

This would probably take too long to teach.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from `getUserById`, so until an explicit return is added to a function in JavaScript, the result from calling it will always be `undefined`.

Your `result` function is simply a callback. While it is indeed returning a value, that value isn't further being used in `getUserById` or being passed on to anything else, mainly because you're not returning anything from your `then`/`catch` blocks.

Suggested reading on Promises: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises